# How to extract data from a txt.readlines()?

Tags: python, file

I have a code that seems to have a slight issue it reads the file... But the issue is it can not identify the words/letters this is what i mean `extract('test.txt',('A','E','I','O','U'))` the `test.txt` is a txt file and the `('A','E','I','O','U')` is the words i want to find.

my code:

```
def extract(file,find=()):
  with open(str(file),'r') as file:
    find = list(find)
    read_file = file.readlines()
    
    num1 = 0
    num = num1-1
    for vals in find:
      num1 += 1
    pass  
  
    for finds in read_file:
      linef = str(finds)
      main_obj = find[num]
        
      if main_obj in linef:
        print("Yay")
        
      elif linef != main_obj:
        print("NO")
        
      else:
          print("???")
    pass  


extract('test.txt',('A','E','I','O','U'))
```

What my output is:

```
NO
NO
NO
NO
Yay
```

This is the expected output:

```
Yay
Yay
Yay
Yay
Yay
```

inside `test.txt`:

```
A
E
I
O
U
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include `test.txt` that you're using in your example.

Comment: In the second `for` loop, `num` is always `-1`, so `find[num]` is always the last thing in the `find` sequence passed to the `extract()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just leave this here. If the end result is to compare each variable inside of `find` to each line in `file` then this should do the job:

```
def extract(file, find=()):
    with open(file) as F:
        contents = F.readlines()

    for line in contents:
        if any([i in line for i in find]):
            print("Yay")
        else:
            print("NO")

extract("test.txt", ('A','E','I','O','U'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code:

```
for finds in read_file:
  linef = str(finds)
  main_obj = find[num]
    
  if main_obj in linef:
    print("Yay")
    
  elif linef != main_obj:
    print("NO")
```

you never increment `num` and hence are essentially always comparing `find[-1]` with `main_obj`. I guess you have to increment `num` if there is a match or whatever your requirement is.

```
if main_obj in linef:
  num += 1
  print("Yay")
```

Either way, this would be the most down-to-earth correct way to do what you are required to:

```
for temp in find:
    not_found = True
    for finds in read_files:
        if temp in finds:
            not_found = False
            print("Yay")
            break
        elif temp != finds:
            not_found = True # elif is not needed TBH but just adding for clarity
    if not_found:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: If what I infer from your question is correct, the edit should solve your issue. @PyCoder64

Comment: We might also infer that the usage of `words/letters` in the reference to the `finds` variable that maybe the whole `finds` variable should the checked against each line of the `file`. If that is the case, then maybe a `if any([i in line for i in finds])` may be more efficient.

Comment: @Jarvis I have only 5 lines in `test.txt` but when i add your code i get 15 lines in my output!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your logic and remove this code. because it will always return -1 index on every increment.

```
num1 = 0
num = num1-1
for vals in find:
  num1 += 1
pass
```

Just use one variable and increment it accordingly.

```
def extract(file, find=()):
    num = 0
    with open(str(file), 'r') as file:
        find = list(find)
        print(find)
        read_file = file.read().splitlines()
        print(read_file)

        for finds in read_file:
            linef = str(finds)
            main_obj = find[num]
            num += 1

            if main_obj in linef:
                print("Yay")

            elif linef != main_obj:
                print("NO")

            else:
                print("???")
        pass
```