# How to find how many of the same word are in a file?

Tags: python, file

I want to find/count how many of the same words are in the file. this is what i mean simplified i want to open and read a file then find how many of the same word there is. not any random same word, a word declared by a variable.

Code i found:

```
def extract(file, find=()):
    with open(file) as F:
        contents = F.readlines()

    for line in contents:
        if any([i in line for i in find]):
            print("Yay")
        else:
            print("NO")

extract("test.txt", ('A','E','I','O','U'))
```

the code works but not the reason i need it to work.

Comment: To be fair: That is not "your code". It is exactly the answer to your previous SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413259/how-to-extract-data-from-a-txt-readlines

Comment: Please don't ask repeatedly the same question - given that you've already have the answer and accepted earlier?

Comment: i am sorry @Lydia van Dyke i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you are trying to do.

```py
import re

def extract(doc, find):

    with open(doc, 'r') as txt:
        contents = txt.read()

    word_counts = {}
    tokens = re.findall('\w+', contents)

    tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens]
    find = [s.strip().lower() for s in find]

    for f in find:
        count = 0
        for t in tokens:
            if t == f:
                count +=1
        word_counts[f] = count

    return word_counts

find = ["a", "text"]
print(extract('text.txt',find))

# {'a': 1, 'text': 3}
```

You may want to use Regex or an NLP library to extract more precise tokens to detail with punctuation etc. then pass that text to a count function.

Comment: for performance considerations you should not have lower() and strip() methods in the innermost loop.  You should pre-treat all the find items, and the tokens list, e.g. 'tokens = [token.strip().lower() for token in tokens]` and `find = [s.strip().lower() for s in find]` just before the outer loop.  then your comparison is just `if t==f` which should be much faster.

Comment: Good point, I updated with your suggestions -- Thanks!

Comment: @KJDII it seems to work with only one line of letter seems to not work with multi lines?

Comment: It should work with multi-line text files I tested this with a text file containing three.. make sure you have .read() in place of .readlines().

Comment: @KJDII i ment it as with or without .read() it seems to not work ither

Comment: my output should be {'a': 3, 'e': 5} but my output is {'a':0,'e':0}

Comment: @PyCoder64, a sample of the text and find values would be helpful.

Comment: my text file says:

a
a
a
e
e
e
e
e

Comment: I see, I will update to use regex to extract better tokens for this exact example.  You will need to adjust how you are identifying your tokens to meet your exact needs, the counting mechanism remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Here a pretty pythonic approach:

```
from collections import Counter

wordcounts = Counter(map(lambda x:x.strip().lower(), open("filename.txt",'rt').read().split()))
for f in find:
    if f.strip().lower() in wordcounts:
        print (f,'occurs',wordcounts[f],'times.')
    else:
        print (f,'not found in file.')
```

But a far better word-extractor would use the re module:

add:

```
from re import findall
```

and replace wordcounts assignment with:

```
wordcounts = Counter(map(lambda x:x.lower(),findall(r"\w+",open(filename,'rt').read())))
```

Comment: there is a typo?  Should it be - `collections` import Counter?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that when I went to test it.  Oops.  Corrected. Found another typo too when I changed a variable name.